# What is the best online game framework for Python?

Tags: python

I want create online game with Python. Is there any framework or library to make it easier? I would like it if the framework provided things like character attributes, such as health.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not one. If you are interested in making online games in Python, I encourage you to look at [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org/), which does have a networking interface. However, it is not nearly as high-level as you want - there is nothing like health or HP built into it.

Comment: i saw panda3D but i want something for online structure

Comment: http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/DC_File

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at BigWorld ([www.bigworldtech.com](http://www.bigworldtech.com/index/index.php)). It's not free, though, not even particularly cheap.

Comment: Nor does the client use any Python, nor have I ever heard anyone who worked on a BigWorld project talk about how much they liked it.

Comment: Well, except that quote on their front page from a guy whose game took four years and was then canceled before private beta.

Comment: Well, I did hear at least one developer saying he approved of BigWorld after having used it. Besides, it's the only framework I can think of that has "online" and "python" in a same sentence.